# Rails URL parameters not able to be used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to, actioncontroller

I'm passing a `suggestion_id` parameter via `link_to` so that it can be saved as part of a `create` action in a different controller.

```
<%= link_to "I'm interested", new_interested_path(:controller => :interested, 
    :suggestion_id => suggestion.id, :method => :get), :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>
```

Here is the resultant URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/interesteds/new?controller=interested&method=get&suggestion_id=1
```

According to [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/action_controller_overview.html), I should be able to use the following code to access the `suggestion_id` parameter in my create action in this other controller:

```
@interested.suggestion_id = params[:suggestion_id]
```

This is not true, however. Whenever an "interested" object is created the suggestion_id is nil. What gives and why can't I find documentation to help me with this? And don't tell me to look [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html) because I've already done that as well. It was not super helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try it like this:

```
<%= link_to "I'm interested", new_interested_path(:suggestion_id => suggestion.id), :method => :get, :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>
```

The `new_interested_path` method already indicates it is using the 'interested' resource and thus the controller name doesn't need to (and shouldn't) be passed in.  And the method shouldn't be part of the URL, it's the http method that rails will use when sending the request to the URL.

Your point regarding `suggestion_id` being nil would depend on what you are trying to do.  In your case you are not accessing the `create` action, but rather the `new` action which you may use to initialize an object for form rendering.  In order to get the `suggestion_id` passed to the `create` action on submit, your `new.html.erb` view template would need to have a field (possibly a hidden field) that assigns that attribute - something like this:

```
form_for @interested, interesteds_path do |f|
  ... # other fields
  f.hidden_field :suggestion_id
  f.submit
end
```

When this form is submitted, `params[:interested]` would contain values for all the fields that were populated (including `suggestion_id`) and can be used to build and create a new ActiveRecord object.

Your controller actions should look something like this:

```
def new
  @interested = Interested.new(:suggestion_id => params[:suggestion_id])
end

def create
  @interested = Interested.new(params[:interested])
  if @interested.save
    # do something
  else
    # alert user
  end
end
```

Comment: So that didn't work... I added what you said, as well as the following information to my interesteds contoller:   
`def new
    @interested = Interested.new
    @interested.suggestion_id = params([:suggestion_id])

def create
    @interested = Interested.new(params[:interested])
    @interested.user_id = current_user.id
    @interested.suggestion_id = (params[:suggestion_id])` 

So now when I submit, I get closer, but an error: [link](https://skitch.com/davidrossdegroot/e285y/action-controller-exception-caught)

Comment: The parenthesis in `@interested.suggestion_id = params([:suggestion_id])` in the `new` action is incorrect.  It should be `params[:suggestion_id]`. And you shouldn't assign ` @interested.suggestion_id = (params[:suggestion_id])` in the `create` action - that field is passed as part of the params[:interested] hash.

Comment: That was it brother!!! Not sure if you can do this, but if you edit the post to include information about the "new" action in the interesteds controller, I will accept the answer. Thanks so much. Again, I wish that there was better documentation about this. How did you figure it out?